# How to manage odd record(s) in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My SSRS report dataset generates 6 colums as shown below. Report is grouped by RepName.
The portfolio column is populated with either A and B. A is regular name and B is odd name. Whenever there is B, I would like to change the background color of that particular cell to red and MOVE the odd record(s) to the top when the report runs. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
RepName    AppID   DealerName   BuyerName   AmtFinc  Portfolio
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Conditional Formatting of Cell Background

1. Right-click the `Portfolio` field to access properties
   [image: Textbox Properties]
2. Open the expression editor for `Fill color:` on the `Fill` tab
   [image: Fill color expression editor]
3. Enter the expression to evaluate value of the `Portfolio` field and set color as appropriate.
   [image: Fill color expression text]

---

## Sorting

You have two options for sorting results, either in the dataset or in the table/matrix on the report. Test to see which works best for your situation.

### Dataset sort

Assuming the column name is `Portfolio` in the database, add the following to your dataset query:

```
ORDER BY Portfolio DESC;
```

### Tablix sort

1. Right-click the tablix in report design:

   [image: Tablix property]
2. Set descending sort on the `Portfolio` field:
   [image]

Keep in mind that if you want **all** rows with `Portfolio` value of `B` to sort at the top of the report, you'll need to remove the `RepName` grouping. See sample output:

### Grouped

[image: Output grouped]

### Not grouped

[image: Output not grouped]

Comment: beargle, thanks very much. I appreciate your effort and the way making things clear.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two requirements here:

- Order by Portfolio.
- Conditional Highlighting.

To order your table as required, just order by **Portfolio** (from Z to A, so *B* is first) then by **RepName**.

Conditional Highlighting is pretty standard; set the TextBox **Background Color** property to:

```
=IIf(Fields!Portfolio.Value = "B", "Red", "White")
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something here as these don't seem particularly unusual requirements.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your suggestion. The RepName column is already grouped by RepName.  So would you suggest to ungroup it first and follow your suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Is `Portfolio` based on `RepName`? If so, every `RepName` row will have the same `Portfolio` value so you shouldn't need to ungroup it, the ordering will just be based on the first value in the group. Just make sure you apply the sorting at the lowest level, so it's not overridden by a child group level sort.

Comment: Actually RepName is classified based on the Portfolio status. So as the status changes from A to B I want to make it red. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements. So you can have different `Portfolio` values for the same `RepName`? Are you talking about detail rows of the table or group header rows? Perhaps if you added a DataSet with half a dozen rows and how you need these to be displayed that would be helpful. That said, the advice in the answer still applies.